# Swiper js - filtering/removing slides

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm facing a problem playing with swiperjs.
I need to filter swiper slides but according to the swiper API we have some methods designed for slides manipulation as swiper.removeSlide(slideIndex) etc. This is fine however when we run this method we are removing .swiper-slide from DOM too which i don't want to do :). I was hoping that i would be able to manipulate swiper slides in this way swiper.slides = [slide1,slide2] and for example hide the rest of the slides by "display: none". What I'm gonna do is to have some sort of slides duplications in another DOM element but I'm just wondering if it is any different approach?
or somebody was having similar issue?

thanks folks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.